# Razor DropDownListFor SelectList, How to bind inumberable selectitems or how to do this?

Tags: c#, razor

Following code work fine, I am using this method of binding in many view and so i am trying to convert in to a static function. following are my attempts. can someone help me to highlight how to do this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardExpiryYear, new SelectList(
    new[] { new { Text = "- -", Value = (string)null } }.Concat(
    Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10)
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Text = r.ToString(),
        Value = r.ToString()
    })),
    "Value", "Text")
)
```

---

Following were my attempts:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardExpiryYear, IEnumerable < SelectListItem > vmConstants.listExpiryYearTest)

public static SelectList listExpiryYearTest()
        {
            var listExpYears = new SelectList(
                        new[] { new { Text = "- -", Value = (string)null } }.Concat(
                        Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 10)
                        .Select(r => new
                        {
                            Text = r.ToString(),
                            Value = r.ToString()
                        })),
                        "Value", "Text");
            return listExpiryYears; 
        }
```

Comment: is it only the "inner SelectList" which is shared, or do you have many "models" with a CardExpiryYear property ?

Comment: there is model called payment and one of its property is public string CardExpiryYear { get; set; }, I have maintained all my constants in a separate class where i wanted to create a function which can return list of years. i have attached the function above which i have tried earlier .

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks wrong:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CardExpiryYear, 
    IEnumerable < SelectListItem > vmConstants.listExpiryYearTest)
```

You have a method that returns the select list, so insert the method call as the second argument passed to `DropDownListFor()`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.CardExpiryYear, 
    vmConstants.listExpiryYearTest() )
```

This assumes that you have a class named "vmConstants" with a static method called "listExpiryYearYest".

Side note: consider using standard c# [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx), which capitalize the class and method names.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CardYearExpiry, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.CardYearExpiry,  null)
```

This is the way I usually do it when I need a dropdownlist binding to an IEnumerable. The ViewBag is just a new select list I have declared in C# whilst the view is rendering (example below).

```
ViewBag.CardYearExpiry = item.Select(s => new SelectListItem
{
  Value = s.Id,
  Text = s.Name
}).OrderBy(o => o.Text);
```